# add tracking to mandrill send-template

Tags: tracking, mandrill

My mandrill keeps saying my message is not opened when I call messages/info.json despite I have added tracking.

here is my request:

```
{
"key": "mykey",
"template_name": "message",
"template_content": {},
"message": {
    "html": null,
    "text": null,
    "subject": "test",
    "from_email": "info@test.io",
    "from_name": "test",
    "to": [
        {
            "email": "rob.proesmans@test.be",
            "name": "rob",
            "type": "to"
        }
    ],
    "headers": null,
    "important": null,
    "track_opens": true,
    "track_clicks": true,
```

etc..

my mandrill response when i call /messages/info.json

```
{
"ts": 1455290984,
"_id": "3e5877fc43044841ab505f999b4a5b00",
"state": "sent",
"subject": "test",
"email": "rob.proesmans@redtree.be",
"tags": {},
"opens": 0,
"clicks": 0,
"smtp_events": [
    {
        "ts": 1455290986,
        "type": "sent",
        "diag": "250 2.0.0 OK 5E/A9-30218-21AFDB65",
        "source_ip": "198.2.134.26",
        "destination_ip": "94.143.184.119",
        "size": 23062
    }
],
"resends": {},
"sender": "info@redtree.io",
"template": "pocmessage",
"opens_detail": {},
"clicks_detail": {}
```

}

After 5minutes.. still no result after opening the mail..
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I takes around 2 hours till Mandrill knows when your mail is opened.